# Spinner is not populated in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am trying to add 2 spinner in a fragment.These spinners are interconnected.When user select a value,2nd spinner will be populated with value.
Example:1st spinner have 2 values as "Car" & "Bus".
When users select "car",2nd spinner will be populated by color of the car as "Red","Blue".Again,if user select Bus,2nd spinner will be populated by color of bus as "Green","White".

I have made this in mainactivity successfully.But when  I try to implement in a fragment ,2nd spinner is not populated and also there is no error showing.

I am providing the code that I have tried to implement in fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_form, container, false);
    //spCountries = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.idCrimePlace);

//set the spinners
crimePlace = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idCrimePlace);
metro = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idMetro);

crimePlace.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
crimePlace.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String spCrimePlace= String.valueOf(crimePlace.getSelectedItem());
            //Toast.makeText(this, crimePlace, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(spCrimePlace.contentEquals("Car")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Red");
                list.add("Blue");
                list.add("Others");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                metro.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            if(spCrimePlace.contentEquals("Bus")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Green");
                list.add("White");
                list.add("Other");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                metro.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting adapter for `crimePlace` spinner?
Why there is `setOnItemSelectedListener` called twice on `crimePlace`?
The second `setOnItemSelectedListener` will override first.

Comment: in same fragment. metro spinner will be populated onItemSelected of crimePlace spinner.

Comment: crimePlace  spinner will get value from string.xml

not twice,1st one is 
<pre>crimePlace.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);</pre>
I have also tried by commenting the line but not working :(
@radekJ

Comment: Uncoment this toast and instead of crimePlace show there spCrimePlace AND check what is this value. Or use debugger

Comment: uncomenting toast ,shows error "cannot resolve method(anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, android.widget.Spinner, int)

Comment: this is a OnItemSelectedListener, you must provide a Context as first parameter: `Toast.makeText(getActivity, spCrimePlace, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Toast is not working....

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your adapter like:

```
ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

And also use `equals()` instead of `contentEquals`

Comment: ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
showing error in this.getActivity().

Comment: try use only `getActivity`  or `getContext`

Comment: i use getActivity().But still not populated metro spinner

Comment: print a log inside if condition to see it enter in or not...also try `getContext`

Comment: check what the toast message prints: `Toast.makeText(getActivity, crimePlace, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  also use `equals`

Comment: and check if `onItemSelected` is called by putting there `Log.d`, `Toast` or by attaching debugger and using breakpoints